# listbox does not contain a definition for 'Selected'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code in C# wpf page

```
listBox1.Items[i].Selected = !listBox1.Items[i].Selected;
```

and it produce this error:

> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Active

also I've been tested   listBox1.SetSelected(i, true); still the same error

Comment: `listBox1.Items[i]` doesn't have a property on it `Selected`...

Comment: Seems like this line is in loop, The item object in listBox is usually a string, so it doesn't have Selected property. Post your looping code, so we can understand what you really want to do

Comment: based on your edited question, What error are you getting for `listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listbox doesn't have a property 'Selected'. You need to use 'SelectedItem'

See MSDN for more info: [Listbox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listBox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2):

A [`ListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an `Items` property which is a collection as specified by the ItemSource.

You need `ListBox.SelectedItem` and if it is strongly typed you will need to cast back to your type.